# Incrementally copy data from one (horrible) database to another (nicer) database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, clone, advantage-database-server

As with all my questions at the moment, I'm working with the "Advantage Database Server" on a remote machine, which is slow, and clumsy.

It would be great if I could write a quick script to dump changes made to the "live" system into a nice PostgreSQL database.

The existing database is made up of about 30 tables, however only about 7 of these are actively updated.

I have the ones I want copied defined as models already.

The ADS tables all have a pseudo-column of "ROWID" which should stay the same within the existing database (according to the documentation) ... this is also often used as the "Primary Key" on the ADS tables except for the fact that it isn't indexed!

I'm proposing to create a new table in PostgreSQL with a copy of this data, including the pseudo-column ROWID (not a PostgreSQL reserved word, I believe), and then doing a comparison of the live ADS data to the PostgreSQL equivalent.

```
class Determinand << AisBase
  self.table_name = 'DETS'
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  self.primary_key = 'DET'
end

class PgDeterminand << PostgresBase
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  self.primary_key = 'DET'
end

livet = Determinand.select("ROWID").map(&:ROWID)
devt = PgDeterminand.select("ROWID").map(&:ROWID)

new_dets = Determinand.find_by(ROWID: livet - devt)
# or maybe
(livet - devt).map do |rid|
  Determinand.find_by(ROWID: rid)
end
```

and then loop through the `new_dets` to create new `PgDeterminand` rows ...

the reading is very slow:

```
puts Benchmark.measure { livet=Determinand.select("ROWID").map(&:ROWID) }
  0.196957   0.098432   0.295389 ( 26.503560)

livet.count
 => 6136
```

and this is not a big table ...

can anyone think of a clearer way to look at doing this?

-- EDIT --

Okay, I've copied all the existing models to an "Ads" folder, created new objects in the Postgres (based on the existing schema.rb file), removed all the `belongs_to` from the models (no referential integrity on the AIS LIMS tables!) and I can quickly and easily copy the data to the new tables like follows:

```
def force_utf8 (hsh)
  hsh.each_with_object({}) do |(i,j),a|
    a[i]= j.present? && j.is_a?(String) ? j.encode("utf-8", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?') : j
  end
end

Ads::Determinand.all.as_json.each do |d|
  Determinand.create(force_utf8(d))
end
```

this isn't an incremental yet, but using the ROWID from the existing table, I should be able to work from there

-- EDIT 2 --

ROWID appears to be essentially sequential for each table ... except that it uses the order '[A-Za-z0-9+/]' ... awesome!

I was hoping to do just a "greater than last stored ROWID" for new data in the "Live" system:

```
Ads::Determinand.where(Ads::Determinand.arel_table['ROWID'].gt(Determinand.maximum(:ROWID))).as_json.each do |d|
  Determinand.create(force_utf8(d))
end
```

but this obviously doesn't cope with ROWIDs after an ending "zz":

`CFTquNARAXIFAAAezz` is greater than `CFTquNARAXIFAAAe+D`

Comment: I think you would achieve near-real-time replication by driving this from the Advantage database server end, as the server can notify you whenever a record is inserted via the Advantage Events (Notifications) mechanism. You could set up a TRIGGER on any insert operation you are interested in, to fire an event (via the  sp_SignalEvent procedure) that passes the new RowID to a listening client application that would create the PostgreSQL record.

https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sp_signalevent.htm

Comment: ooh, that sounds really useful!  do you know if this can work without a data dictionary? (long story, don't ask :( )

Comment: Yes this can work without a data dictionary, although it is less transparent: you will have to call the sp_SignalEvent() procedure from all the client applications wherever and whenever a record is inserted.

Comment: Alternatively, as long as you are using DBF tables, I believe it is possible to create a data dictionary and still have the client applications accessing the tables as free tables. That will allow you to set set up the necessary TRIGGERs on the data dictionary on the server itself. Note that this is not possible with ADT tables, because they can no longer be accessed as free tables as soon as they are added to a data dictionary.

Comment: pretty certain it's all ADT tables ... unfortunately

Comment: Why not add all the ADT tables to a data dictionary and modify all client apps to connect to the data dictionary instead of the directory?

Comment: I don't actually have access to control the main client app :( I really would like to get this sorted properly, but the installer of the database obviously was used to a very early version of the database ... we have individual file access and individual file authentication.  My guess is that they intentionally did this for some reason

Comment: Ah, tricky. I guess it's back to your ruby-on-rails method then.
One possible solution would be to add an AutoIncrement primary key to each table you are interested in. That should be a lot faster than using the non-indexed RowID key.
But if you don't have access to the main client source code you'd have to test the client app carefully in case it does something that is not compatible with the new field.

Comment: thanks @dougwoodrow it has been helpful, if not usable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have this mostly sorted now:

### Schema Initialisation

first I moved all my models to an "Ads" directory (adding in "module Ads" to each model), set up 2 databases in my project and gathered the "existing" schema using `rake db:schema:dump`

then I created new models (e.g.):

```
rails g model Determinand
```

I then copied the existing model from the `ads_schema.rb` to the rails migration, and `rake db:migrate:postgres`

### Initial Data Dump

I then did an initial data export/import.

On smaller tables, I was able to use the following:

```
Ads::Client.all.as_json.each do |c|
  Client.create(c)
end
```

but on larger tables I had to use a CSV export from the ADS, and a `pgloader` script to bring in the data:

```
load CSV
    from 'RESULTS.csv'
        having fields
        (
            SAMPNUM, DET, JOB, GLTHAN, INPUT, OUTPUT, RESULT, ERROR, GENFLAG,
            SPECFLAG, STATFLAG, COMPFLAG, REPEAT, DETORDER, ANALYST, DETDATE [date format 'DD/MM/YYYY'],
            DETTIME, LOGDATE [date format 'DD/MM/YYYY'], APPROVED [date format 'DD/MM/YYYY'], APPROVEDBY, INSTRUMENT, FILENAME, LINE_NO,
            TEXTRESULT, DATATYPE, SUITE, TEST, SECTION, UKAS, MCERTS, ACCRED, DEVIATING,
            PRINT_1, PRINT_1_BY, PRINT_1_AT, PRINT_2, PRINT_2_BY, PRINT_2_AT, LABEL, LABLOCN
        )
    into postgresql://$user:$password@localhost/ads_project
        TARGET TABLE results
        TARGET COLUMNS
        (
            'SAMPNUM', 'DET', 'JOB', 'GLTHAN', 'INPUT', 'OUTPUT', 'RESULT', 'ERROR', 'GENFLAG',
            'SPECFLAG', 'STATFLAG', 'COMPFLAG', 'REPEAT', 'DETORDER', 'ANALYST', 'DETDATE',
            'DETTIME', 'LOGDATE', 'APPROVED', 'APPROVEDBY', 'INSTRUMENT', 'FILENAME', 'LINE_NO',
            'TEXTRESULT', 'DATATYPE', 'SUITE', 'TEST', 'SECTION', 'UKAS', 'MCERTS', 'ACCRED', 'DEVIATING',
            'PRINT_1', 'PRINT_1_BY', 'PRINT_1_AT', 'PRINT_2', 'PRINT_2_BY', 'PRINT_2_AT', 'LABEL', 'LABLOCN'
        )
    with csv header,
        fields optionally enclosed by '"',
        fields terminated by ',',
        drop indexes

    before load do
        $ alter table results alter column created_at drop not null, alter column updated_at drop not null; $$

    after load do
        $ update results set created_at = "DETDATE", updated_at=NOW() where created_at is null and updated_at is null; $,
        $ alter table results alter column created_at set not null, alter column updated_at set not null; $
;
```

### Incremental Updates

for the incremental updates I have to do something like the following:

On smaller tables (~ <1000 rows):

```
Ads::DetLimit.where.not(ROWID: DetLimit.pluck(:ROWID)).as_json.each do |d|
  DetLimit.create(force_utf8(d))
end
```

On Larger tables I need to use Ruby to limit the IDs that have changed (essentially white-list not black-list):

```
zzz = SuiteDet.pluck(:ROWID)
yyy = Ads::SuiteDet.pluck(:ROWID)

Ads::SuiteDet.where(ROWID: yyy-zzz).as_json.each do |d|
  SuiteDet.create(force_utf8(d))
end
```

### Deployment

I created a `CopyTable` script to run, so that I can batch it, with just the increments now, and it takes about 2 minutes to run, which is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ADS, but IMO it'll be a good start if you have access to modify the dsign by adding necessary indexes to it.

Also `Determinand.pluck(:id)` is always MUCH faster than `Determinand.select("ROWID").map(&:ROWID)`

Comment: I can't really change the live system, and because rowid is a pseudo column I have to select it before plucking ... Map and pluck are about the same speed (I checked) in this case, because the database access is so damn slow :-\ ... I'm hoping to come the data into new tables in postgres so that I can manipulate the structure

Comment: is exporting to csv an option for you? you can use cronjob to do this if you always need (almost) up-to-date data and download it using ftp/scp anytime you need updated data, and import it. but this way prevents you from getting realtime data

Comment: It's a possibility, but might be harder than using the ruby to do it. (it might be easier to use the ruby to write the CSV) ... it would be possible to use pgloader after that though, so it's a possibility